# Port 53 UDP is "open". Systemd-resolved is disabled and no process is listed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, systemd-resolved

I want to free my port 53 on my Ubuntu 20.04 system.

```
sudo ss -lnup
```

gives this output

```
antani@strappanai:~ » sudo ss -lnup                       
State                    Recv-Q                   Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                       Peer Address:Port                   Process                   
UNCONN                   0                        0                                                0.0.0.0:53                                              0.0.0.0:*                                                
UNCONN                   0                        0                                                   [::]:53                                                 [::]:*
```

As you can see, the "process" column is empty. What could be that is using that port and how to discover it?

Comment: google for "systemd-resolve" uses port 53

Comment: @Andra so where's the pid?

Comment: Among other possible causes here's my list 1/ root isn't really root (containers...) 2/ kernel listens to this port for a tunnel interface 3/ compromised system. Any additional information to dismiss these cases?

Comment: @Andra as I wrote in the subject that daemon is off and it would have been written in the "process" column using the command I used.

Comment: @A.B that was your intuition #2. The wireguard VPN was configured on that port. I got to know that by grepping 53 in the whole "/etc" directory though. Aren't there any cleaner, more effective ways to realize what is going on in this situation? Like, seeing what kernel module is responsible for that port usage? Thank you.

Comment: It is worth to answer this question! And sorry for my stupid tip :(

Comment: well I actually don't have an answer. I mean, I found how what that is but by other means. I think it would be great to know if there's a way to distinguish what kernel module is responsible of that.